# ActionLink doesn't generate proper routing url for actions which has two parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.actionlink

In the view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = 1, year = 1 })
```

In the controller

```
// GET: /Forecasts/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int id, short year)
{
    ...
}
```

It generated a url like

`http://<localhost>/controllername/actionname/1?year=1`

I would expect the actionlink generate a URL like :
`http://<localhost>/controllername/actionname/?id=1&year=1`

This url cannot be interpreted by MVC default routing, why the URL is not generated in the expected way? Thanks.

**Update**:
Now I found out it was a typo caused this problem for me, but the answer below is still good enough as it help me to further understand the way route works

Comment: because of the default route you're using. Which routes have you declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the default route, which will be formatted like this:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Which means the first parameter will be `id` and will be written just after the `/`, without any named GET parameter.

If you want to have explicit parameters everywhere, just use this route configuration:

```
"{controller}/{action}"
```

If you remove the `id` all your parameters will be named.

Comment: Thank you as now I understand why it is not generating explicit url.

Answer (score 5):

> I would expect the actionlink generate a URL like : `http://<localhost>/controllername/actionname/?id=1&year=1`

You cannot expect something like this if you are using the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Get rid of the `{id}` from the if you expect such url pattern:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: thank you mate, the same answer as as @ppetrov, he responded earlier though. It is a pity that i can not mark both as answers, don't know why.